# Black on white theme in windows 10 terminal

Tags: windows-10, terminal

I just installed new windows 10 terminal. It is simply superb. I want to change the theme to black on white (currently it is white on black). Any configuration available for that? I got some configs for

1. Campbell
2. Solarized Light
3. Solarized Dark and etc

I want the simple putty (black on white) theme

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the color themes at https://github.com/mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Schemes

1. Download and extract the zip file
2. Open "windowsterminal" folder
3. Open any file (.json format)
4. Copy the settings and paste them in "schemas" section of windows terminal settings

After copying, it should look something like below

```
// To view the default settings, hold "alt" while clicking on the "Settings" button.
// For documentation on these settings, see: https://aka.ms/terminal-documentation

{
    "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",

    "defaultProfile": "{c6eaf9f4-32a7-5fdc-b5cf-066e8a4b1e40}",

    "profiles":
    [
        {
            // Make changes here to the powershell.exe profile
            "guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
            "name": "Windows PowerShell",
            "commandline": "powershell.exe",
            "hidden": false
        },
        {
            // Make changes here to the cmd.exe profile
            "guid": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}",
            "name": "cmd",
            "commandline": "cmd.exe",
            "hidden": false
        },
        {
            "guid": "{b453ae62-4e3d-5e58-b989-0a998ec441b8}",
            "hidden": false,
            "name": "Azure Cloud Shell",
            "source": "Windows.Terminal.Azure"
        },
        {
            "guid": "{c6eaf9f4-32a7-5fdc-b5cf-066e8a4b1e40}",
            "hidden": false,
            "name": "Ubuntu-18.04",
            "source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl",
            "acrylicOpacity" : 0.5,
            "closeOnExit" : true,
            "colorScheme" : "AtomOneLight",
            "cursorColor" : "#000000",
            "cursorShape" : "bar",
            "fontFace" : "Consolas",
            "fontSize" : 12,
            "historySize" : 9001,
            "icon" : "ms-appx:///ProfileIcons/{9acb9455-ca41-5af7-950f-6bca1bc9722f}.png",
            "padding" : "0, 0, 0, 0",
            "snapOnInput" : true,
            "useAcrylic" : false
        }
    ],

    // Add custom color schemes to this array
    "schemes": [
        {
            "name": "AtomOneLight",
            "black": "#000000",
            "red": "#de3e35",
            "green": "#3f953a",
            "yellow": "#d2b67c",
            "blue": "#2f5af3",
            "purple": "#950095",
            "cyan": "#3f953a",
            "white": "#bbbbbb",
            "brightBlack": "#000000",
            "brightRed": "#de3e35",
            "brightGreen": "#3f953a",
            "brightYellow": "#d2b67c",
            "brightBlue": "#2f5af3",
            "brightPurple": "#a00095",
            "brightCyan": "#3f953a",
            "brightWhite": "#ffffff",
            "background": "#f9f9f9",
            "foreground": "#2a2c33"
        }
    ],

    // Add any keybinding overrides to this array.
    // To unbind a default keybinding, set the command to "unbound"
    "keybindings": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy color schemes from the defaults.json by Alt-Clicking on the settings (settings are found in the dropdown menu in the tab bar).

Copy all the color schemes.  Then in your settings.json file (simple left click on the settings), replace the "schemas" array with the array you copied in defaults.json.   You should end up with something like this:

```
"schemes":
[ 
    {
        "name": "Campbell",
        // ...
    },
    {
        "name": "Campbell Powershell",
        // ...
    },
    // ...
]
```

Then, further up, you should find a profile defaults object that is empty.  Create a "colorScheme" property in there and set the value to the schema name you want.  You will end up with something like this:

```
"profiles":
{
    "defaults":
    {
        // Put settings here that you want to apply to all profiles.
        "colorScheme": "One Half Light"
    },
    "list":
    [ 
        /*...you will see things like cmd, powershell, or ubuntu/WSL profiles here*/
    ]
```

From there, you can add new schemas to the schemas array and then choose them by name.