# change selected text color in windows terminal

Tags: windows-10, terminal, colors

Windows terminal gained a lot of traction since its release. I was trying to customize it and found that I cannot use light themes in it. Selected text color is by default having grey color and with my [black on white background](https://superuser.com/questions/1492236/black-on-white-theme-in-windows-10-terminal), the contrast isn't good enough to identify the selected block.

Is there an option to change that?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this answer on Windows Terminal Preview,
You can now change the color of the selectionBackground by opening the .json file for the configurations of the terminal and changing the value to the color you want on the scheme you are currently using, e.g;

```
"selectionBackground": "#00FF00"
```

Remember the color is Hexadecimal rgb where the color is represented as #RRGGBB, you can go from #000000 black to #FFFFFF white.

Also  you can now create your own scheme if you want and have a bit more customization on the available colors.

More about this on the [Creating your own color scheme](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/color-schemes#creating-your-own-color-scheme) section in the documentation of Windows Terminal.

Happy customizing...